# Implementing Doubly Linked List in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

I was trying to implement a doubly linked list with the following functions:

```
_insertItemAfterNode(self,index) 

_nodeBeforeIndex(self, index)



insertItemAtTheFront(self,item)

insertItemAtTheEnd(self,item)

insertItemAtIndex(self, index, item)
```

The last three functions should use the first two private methods.
This is what I have so far but I can't seem to work it. Any help is appreciated!!!

```
# DoublyLinkedLists

class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, prev = None, data=None, next = None):
        self._prev = prev
        self._data = data
        self._next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._data)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node(%s,%s,%s)" % (repr(self._prev), repr(self._data), repr (self._next))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other == None:
            return False
        else:
            return self._prev == other._prev and self._data == other._data and self._next == other._next`enter code here`

class DoublyLinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._first = Node(None, None, None)
        self._length = 0
        self._last = Node(None, None, None)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._length

    def _insertItemAfterNode(self,item,aNode):
        newNode = Node(aNode._prev, item, aNode._next)
        aNode._next= newNode._prev
        aNode._prev=newNode._next
        self._length += 1

    def _nodeBeforeIndex(self, index):
        if 0 <= index <= self._length:
            aNode = self._first
            for i in range(index):
                aNode = aNode._next
            return aNode
        else:
            raise IndexError

    def _nodeAfterIndex(self, index):
        if 0<= index <= self.length:
            aNode = self._last
            for i in range(index):
                aNode = aNode._prev
            return aNode
        else:
            raise IndexError

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._nodeBeforeIndex(index)._next._data

    def insertAtEnd(self, item):
        self._nodeAfterIndex(item)        

    def __iter__(self):
        return DoublyLinkedListIterator(self)

    def __setitem__(self, index, item):
        self._nodeBeforeIndex(index)._next._data = item

    def insertItemAtTheFront(self, item):
        self._insertItemAfterNode(item, self._nodeBeforeIndex(0))

    def insertItemAtTheEnd(self, item):
        self._insertItemAfterNode(item, self._nodeBeforeIndex(self._length))

    def insertItemAtIndex(self, index, item):
        '''Valid range 0 <= index <= length.'''
        self._insertItemAfterNode(item, self._nodeBeforeIndex(index))

    def __iter__(self):
        return DoublyLinkedListIterator(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        #used by print in abscence of __str__ .
        plist = []
        for item in self:
            plist.append(item)
        return "DoublyLinkedList(%s)" % str(plist)

class DoublyLinkedListIterator(object):

    def __init__(self, aList):
        self._list = aList
        self._currentIndex = -1
        self._currentNode = self._list._first

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._currentIndex == self._list._length - 1:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self._currentIndex += 1
            self._currentNode = self._currentNode._next
            return self._currentNode._data

def main():

    x = DoublyLinkedList()

    x.insertItemAtTheEnd(45)

    print(x)

main()
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Are you getting exceptions, or is it just not doing what you expect in some situations. Can you give an example of a call or series of calls that don't work? There's a lot of code here, and it's not at all obvious where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things strange with your code. Let's dig into the first problem that I found:

```
def _insertItemAfterNode(self,item,aNode):
    newNode = Node(aNode._prev, item, aNode._next)
    aNode._next= newNode._prev
    aNode._prev=newNode._next
    self._length += 1
```

Assume that you have:

`prevNode <-> aNode <-> nextNode`

You now create a `newNode` which points to `prevNode` as its previous and `nextNode` as its follow-up. Then you reverse the pointers of `aNode`. `prevNode` still thinks its following node is `aNode`, but `aNode` now thinks that its following node is `prevNode` again.

```
              /---------\
       /----> aNode <    v 
prevNode <--------/  \-- nextNode
       ^                 ^
        \---- newNode --/
```

Which is not nearly what you want:

```
prevNode <-> aNode <-> newNode <-> nextNode
```

Here's a better version:

```
def _insertItemAfterNode(self,item,aNode):
    # If the new Node follows aNode, than its preceeding node is aNode,
    # not aNode._prev!
    newNode = Node(aNode, item, aNode._next)
    # Now we need to make aNode point at its new following Node, newNode
    aNode._next = newNode
    # And finally, we need to make the following Node notice that 
    # its preceeding Node has changed.
    newNode._next._prev = newNode
    self._length += 1
```

This doesn't care about any edge cases, for example what to do if `aNode` is the last node in the linked list.

What I recommend is that you take out a piece of paper and draw how the different links need to be changed for each of the operations that you need to make, because it is hard to keep all this in your head.

Make sure that you look at all the edge cases, ie. putting into an empty list, putting in item into the first and last positions.

And finally, while shuffling links around, always double check where each link is pointing at each instruction, and not to drop any nodes accidentally.

Comment: How do I go about printing it out in a list? or making it iterable?

Answer (score 2):

I see two immediate issues with your code. There may be more issues that I haven't noticed, but these will probably prevent you from seeing any others until they are fixed.

The first issue is very simple. You have two sentinel nodes, `_first` and `_last` in your `DoublyLinkedList` class. However, they're not linked to each other, so when more nodes are added later, they won't be connected to both sentinels like they should be.

You can fix this by changing the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._first = Node(None, None, None)
    self._length = 0
    self._last = Node(self._first, None, None)    # pass first node as an arg here
    self._first._next = self._last                # make a link back too
```

The second issue is how you're adding nodes. There are a couple of places where you're assigning values from the `_prev` or `_next` attributes of a node, rather than referring to the node itself.

Lets think of a list containing `A` and `C` nodes, and you want to insert `B` in between them. You need to make `B`'s node link to both `A` and `C`, and then modify `C` and `A` to link back to it. In your code, `A` is `aNode`, `B` is `newNode` and `C` is  (at the start) `aNode._next`.

```
def _insertItemAfterNode(self, item, aNode):
    newNode = Node(aNode, item, aNode._next)     # link B to A and C
    aNode._next._prev = newNode                  # link C back to B
    aNode._next = newNode                        # and A to B too!
    self._length += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have updated it. Anymore comments are greatly appreciated!  How do I go about printing and interating?